# Is there a way to disable a Jenkins plugin for a single job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, sensu

I use the [Build timeout plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin) to alert when jobs are stuck. I have one job that triggers this alert because it contains a step with a long execution time. I would like to disable the build timeout plugin but only for that job, is there a way to do so? I'm using Jenkins v2.22.

We don't use the built-in option for the job not to terminate on timeout, we use sensu plugins to monitor the state of the likelyStuck variable.

Comment: What about unchecking the 'Abort the build if its stuck' in the job configuration ?

Comment: Forgot to clarify, for alerting reasons we don't use that option. Instead we use a sensu alert that creates an alert if the likelyStuck variable is True

Comment: Then you should probably look at Silencing the alert in Sensu, since it's the alert that you want to avoid, not doing anything in Jenkins.

Answer (score 7):

Sadly I just switched jobs and I don't have access to a Jenkins instance (least not yet) so I cannot try it out for you.

That said some ideas quickly jump in my mind that could get you there.

I've had some success with the [conditional build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin though I don't know if it would work for build timeouts.

If not directly perhaps as a means to change some values through the rest API ? Maybe using job [parameters](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) ? You could also split the job in two and call the appropriate one (with or without timeout) using a conditional build step (mentioned above)...

If you are int a pipeline you could use the timeout in a jenkins file.
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-timeout-code-enforce-time-limit.

let me know if any of this is helping you.